# MSVC C++ 17 - warning C4121 "alignment of a member was sensitive to packing"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I have tried the code below on VS2017 (version 15.9) and VS2019 preview - is this a false positive?

```
class Base {};
class Derived1 : public virtual Base {}; // to avoid diamond pattern in real code
class Derived2 : public Base {}; 

struct S1 {
    int i;
    void(Derived1::*func)(); // warning C4121 - see below for full text
};

struct S2 {
    int i;
    void(Derived2::*func)();  // no warning
};

int main()
{

}
```

---

```
r:\cpp2019\cpp2019\cpp2019.cpp(9) : warning C4121 : 'S1' : alignment of a member was sensitive to packing
```

I have made the code as simple as possible (it's not the actual production code obviously). In the production code (a huge codebase), the warning is due to iterating over a map using a range-based for loop. The *loop variable* is of course, `std::pair<keytype, valuetype>`, the value type  is similar to `func` in `struct S1`.

The production code compiled fine in VS2015, but now with VS2017 and the language standard set to C++17, I get this warning.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - that's not possible if you read my explanation. The struct in real code is `std::pair`.

Comment: Are you using `#pragma pack` or passing the `/Zp` flag to the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

It is because of `sizeof(S1::func)==sizeof(void*)*3`, due to support of virtual inheritance, and `sizeof(S2::func)==sizeof(void*)*1`

You can control implementation of pointer-to-member by `#pragma pointers_to_members`. For example with this you'll have warning for both cases.

```
#pragma pointers_to_members( full_generality, virtual_inheritance)
```

As default packing is 8, warning is logical.

Still I think it is a false positive. Although such pointer would appear on apparently misaligned boundary, it is actually implemented as three pointers, so each would be properly aligned.